# Bootstrap empties div on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a div on bootstrap site that I want to hide on desktop and show on mobile. Another div the other way round but somehow on the mobile the div is empty (although it is the same div for testing). The code:

```
    <div class="camera_container hidden-xs">
        <div id="camera" class="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="images/slide-1.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="images/slide-2.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="images/slide-3.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="camera_container visible-xs">
        <div id="camera" class="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="images/slide-1.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="images/slide-2.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="images/slide-3.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `visible-xs` will show only for width lesser than `768px`, not many devices nowadays have such small resolution, you can check if it's working simply by narrowing your browser window. You should also use `visible-xs-block` instead of `visible-xs`